# Logitech Unifying Receiver - How to add a device using code from a standard repository?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, logitech, logitech-unifying, solaar

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

I have a Logitech mouse and keyboard bought separately, each came with their own unifying receiver. If I plug in both unifying receivers then both mouse and keyboard work. I want one of those receivers to live up to its name and do some unifying, i.e. I need to add a device to one of the unifying receivers.

There is an excellent and detailed article about the issue which can be found here:

https://lekensteyn.nl/logitech-unifying.html

To add a device all I have found so far is recommendations to install either:

a) Peter Lekensteyn's "ltunify"

or

b) Daniel Pavel's "Solaar

Both these solutions were originally written approximately 9 or 10 years ago. Does anybody know if Canonical's standard repositories now include a solution for the issue which both Daniel and Peter worked so hard to resolve ?

Comment: Based on `apt search logitech`, both `ltunify` and `solaar` appear to be in the 22.04 *universe* repository - as well as a number of other potentially relevant packages

Comment: @steeldriver Fantastic, thank you. I installed Solaar and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

"steeldriver" gave me the answer I needed, thank you steeldriver. Solaar version 1.1.1 is in Ubuntu's standard repository. There have been a few releases since 1.1.1 but it did the job.

Apart from enabling me to add Logitech devices to a Logitech "Unifying Receiver", Solaar also has other nice features, it displays the battery levels of mouse and keyboard. It also told me that my keyboard's communication is encrypted, this was a reassuring surprise because I had read that communication with the unifying receiver was un-encrypted.

Solaar has been great for me BUT, do I want it running every time I turn the computer on ? I don't see any need for that, nor did I see a GUI option to make it not start every time.

My simple solution was to un-install Solaar, it's done what I needed, if I need it again I will re-install it.

Comment: install and disable it instead of uninstalling. you might need it just when your internet connection is dead ;=)